# Python interpreter does not show in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

When I run `Pycharm` and select new project, there is no interpreter for me to select (please see the screenshot below), so what should I do and how do I fix this, please? I have installed Python 3.5.1 version on my Windows 7.

Thanks!

[image: interpreter screenshot]

Comment: [RTFM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can click right "Gear" icon in setting dialog, then select "Add local" add Python interpreter